# Can you filter a Column in Interactive Report when calling 'Download - Email Option' action?

Tags: plsql, conditional-statements, report, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am working in APEX 5.1.3

Is there a way to filter a column out of an interactive report download (email option). I know how to filter columns out of an excel or html download. You put the following into the conditional area for the column.

```
NVL(:REQUEST,'EMPTY') NOT IN ('PDF', 'XLSX', 'HTML', 'HTMLD')
```

Is there a specific request type for email or a different method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NVL(wwv_flow.g_widget_action, 'EMPTY') NOT IN ('SEND_EMAIL')
```

Comment: That code removed the column on the Email sent out, but the column is also removed from the interactive report in the application after you click the 'Download -> Email'.  The examples above just remove the column from the downloaded copy.